# mounting .vhdx image and iscsi target (windows server 2012 R2) at the same time

Tags: networking, mount, windows-server-2012-r2, iscsi, vhdx

I have questions about .VHDX iscsi target in windows 2012 R2, and mounting the .VHDX image at the same time.

To make my question clear, here is the configuration details:

**fileserver detail**:

**computer name**: fileserver001.company1.local

**vhdx name**: E:\iSCSIVirtualDisks\iVD100.vhdx

**iscsi target**: hpvd100

**iSCSI target IQN**: iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:fileserver001-hpvd100-target

**Access server: (iSCSI initiator)**: IQN:iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:coredata5.company1.local

on the fileserver itself, i can mount

**E:\iSCSIVirtualDisks\iVD100.vhdx** and it become drive **I:**

so at present, if **application server coredata5** is down, I can access the content of iVD100.vhdx from my laptop. I access by first mount iVD100.vhdx as drive I: in server fileserver001 and share I: as network share.

Now i afraid if i turn on coredata5, and iSCSI initiator connects with target, and iVD100.vhdx still mounted as drive I:, and my laptop is accessing drive I:, it will corrupt the data.

So the question, is the approach above okay ? can windows 2012 r2 manage the sharing and locking between iSCSI target and mounted image ?

thanks !

Comment: No. It’s highly unlikely your iscsi target is available when you’ve locked the file by mounting it locally.

Comment: yes you are right. I got message The file couldn't be mounted because it's in use. Thanks.